# Почему eForm ругается после переноса сайта на count?

Tags: modx, evo

Используется modx evo и eform. Перенес сайт с одного хоста на другой и тут кроме главной страницы все выдают ошибку если вставить eform. Причем  форма главной страницы eForm не работает на всех остальных. В чем проблема?

Ошибка:

> Trying to get property 'action' of non-object « Evo Parse Error »
>   Error : count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable

Файл: `docs/assets/snippets/eform/eform.inc.php`

Строка: 707 `$lastitems[count($lastitems)] = "class=\"\""; //removal off empty class attributes`

eform вызов:

```
[!eForm? 
&formid=`contactformidform` 
&subject=`Сообщение с сайта` 
&tpl=`contact_form` 
&report=`report_contact_form` 
&gotoid=`[*id*]`
&thankyou=`thankyou_contact_form`
&to=``
&from=``
&protectSubmit=`1`
&submitLimit=`1`
!]
```

Код формы:

```
<p><span style="color:#900;">[+validationmessage+]</span></p>
<form class="form" action="[~[*id*]~]" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="contact_form" />
    <h2>оставьте сообщение:</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя (обязательно)" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email (обязательно)" required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea  placeholder="Текст сообщения" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group text-right">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn_white" value="Отправить сообщение">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сама глупая ошибка из-за невнимательности. Версия на новом сервере `PHP 7.2`, а `modx evo` на `5.6` работает.